# Content editor view of tree versus Add link view in Rich Text editor

Tags: sitecore-client

Using `Sitecore 9` - We are trying to set a limited view within the `content editor` of the `content tree` and allow users to see the full content tree in the `rich text editor` for cross-linking across the site.

I've checked the read and unchecked read in the `security settings` and so far it's an all of nothing view, am i missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You could take away their Read permissions from the relevant templates or template fields whilst leaving their Read permissions to the actual items - that way when they navigate to the item in Content tree it will say "this item has no fields", but they would be able to select that item in any dialog. But this is somewhat unconventional -- can you tell us more about your particular use case and why are you trying to achieve this? There might be other solutions available.

Comment: We have a group of content authors who are not your usual marketing or web developers that are average everyday users, but are the subject matter experts so they will manage the content for their sections of the site.  They do not need to worry about making changes to sections that they are not using.  They will however from time to time need to link to a page that is somewhere else in the site for more context to the information they are using.    If this is an all or nothing view i can leave it as such, i'm just wanting to help keep the content tree clear for them.

Comment: Try what I recommended in the previous comment. Alternatively, you can leave the `Read` access, but revoke the `Write` access if the only concern is that they might edit something they are not supposed to.

Comment: Thank you Sasha,  we're going to go with the "Read" and revoke the "Write" access so they can see everything but not be able to edit in the Content tree.   I wish i was able to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat unconventional solution could be as follows:
Remove the `Read` permission from the relevant templates (or field sections/or specific fields). Assign `Write` permission to the relevant items.

When the user navigates to the items they will not see any field and won't be able to edit them. At the same time the content items would still be selectable from any `Pick an Item` context menu.